# AWS Lambda Key Error on testing. API Gateway POST method shows no message found

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sns

I am trying to build a server-less contact form using AWS Lambda, AWS API Gateway, Amazon SNS, and AWS Dynamodb. I have a web page which takes name, email and phone number as the form input. I am trying to send these inputs to the dynamodb table on submit. and then, send a notification through AWS SNS. the lambda function is triggered by the API Gateway. When i test the lambda function i am getting KeyError. On submitting , it shows "submitted" on the webpage. I tried with Postman also and there it showed "message not found".

It would be really helpful if someone help me in rectifying this error.

The lambda function is :

```
import json
import boto3
import time

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
sns = boto3.client('sns')
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('contactform')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    body = json.loads(event.get('body', '{}'))
    idn = body['id']
    name = body['name']
    email = body['email']
    number = body['number']
        
    params = {
        'TableName': contactform,
        'Item': {'id': {'S': idn}, 'name': {'S': name}, 'email': {'S': email}, 'number': {'S': number}}
    }
        
    try:
        response = dynamodb.put_item(**params)
        print("Success - item added or updated", response)
        
        response = {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': json.dumps(body),
            'headers': {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*'
            }
        }
        publish_to_sns(body)
        
        print(f"response from: {event['path']} statusCode: {response['statusCode']} body: {response['body']}")
        return response
        
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error", str(e))
        response = {
            'statusCode': 500,  # Internal Server Error
            'body': json.dumps({'error': 'Internal Server Error'}),
            'headers': {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*'
            }
        }
        
        print(f"Error response - {event['path']} statusCode: {response['statusCode']} body: {response['body']}")
        return response
    
def publish_to_sns(body):
    sns_topic_arn = 'arn:aws:sns:ap-south-1:032143978963:contactform'

    sns.publish(
        TopicArn=sns_topic_arn,
        Message=json.dumps(body),
        Subject='New Form Submission',
    )
```

And the html code is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Contact Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<h1>Contact Submission Forms</h1>
<h2>Please enter your contact details. We will be contacting you in 24 hours of form submission. Thank you!</h2>
<div class="form-message" id="form-message"></div>
<form class = "container" id="contactForm" action="https://g6vsqwxfr2.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/deployform" method="POST">

    <div>
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
        <label for="number">Phone number</label>
        <input type="number" id="number" name="number" required>
    </div>
    <br>
    <button id="button" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
    var apiGatewayUrl = 'https://g6vsqwxfr2.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/deployform';
  
    document.getElementById('contactForm').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      var id = genRandomNo();
  
      var form = event.target;
      var formData = new FormData(form);

      var contact = {
        id: id,
        name: formData.get('name'),
        email: formData.get('email'),
        number: formData.get('number')
      };
      console.log(contact)
  
      var xmlhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhr.open('POST', apiGatewayUrl, true);
      xmlhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  
      xmlhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
          var messageElement = document.getElementById('form-message');
          if (xmlhr.status === 200) {
            var response = JSON.parse(xmlhr.responseText);
            console.log(response)
            messageElement.textContent = response.message;
            form.reset();
          } else {
            messageElement.textContent = 'Submitted :)';
          }
        }
      };
  
      var contactJson = JSON.stringify(contact);
      xmlhr.send(contactJson);
      console.log(contactJson)
    });

    function genRandomNo() {
      return Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15) + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15);
    }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```